# using jquery and javascript to change the size of an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django

first of all let me say I have a very short knowledge of javascript and jquery. I'm currently following a tutorial for those topics. With that being said, I was wondering if I can change the size of an image with jquery. For example, I have a code ` this displays image fine, but size is sometimes big and sometimes small. I was looking over some article here https://blog.openshift.com/day-16-goose-extractor-an-article-extractor-that-just-works/
The have this code;

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#myform").on("submit", function(event){
        $("#result").empty();
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#loading').show();
        var url = $("#url").val()
        $.get('/api/v1/extract?url='+url,function(result){
            $('#loading').hide(); 
            $("#result").append("<h4>"+result.title+"</h4>");
            $("#result").append("<img src='"+result.image+"' height='300' width='300'</img>");
            $("#result").append("<p class='lead'>"+result.text+"</p>");
    })


    });

</script>
```

what interests me is `"#result").append("<img src='"+result.image+"' height='300' width='300'</img>");`would I be able to do the same thing with my code {{post.image}}? 
    `

Comment: Well.  You'd want to make those numbers supplied by the script, but that would require knowing the *native resolution* of the image.  Is it being passed via the AJAX? If not, then make it.

Comment: You can wrap your `<img>` tag inside `<div>` tags. Then you can set the width and height of the `<div>` to the amount you want and the width and height of the `<img>` to 100%.

Comment: @DaMaGeX, I think I kinda get what you mean, can you provide some example please...not sure how img tag can be inside div tag

Comment: @ShangWang I'm confused - you can use javascript in a Django template, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can mix `{{ post.image }}` with your javascript without any problems in a Django template.

For instance, you could do this in your Django template:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var image = "{{post.image}}";
  // Beginning of the javascript implementation here.
  $("#result").append("<img src='"+image+"' height='300' width='300'</img>");
  // More javascript.
</script>
```

Comment: Yea I lost my my mind when I commented that, but I guess the blame doesn't belong to an answer. You need some correction as well, it's `var image = "{{post.image}}";` with the quotes.